# Minimize $\frac{2}{1-a}+\frac{75}{10-b}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization, maxima-minima, tangent-line-method

> Let $a,b>0$ and satisfy $a^2+\dfrac{b^2}{45}=1$. Find the minimum
>   value of  $\dfrac{2}{1-a}+\dfrac{75}{10-b}.$

WA gives the result that $\min\left(\dfrac{2}{1-a}+\dfrac{75}{10-b}\right)=21$ with $a=\dfrac{2}{3},b=5$.

Consider making a transformation like this

$$\dfrac{2}{1-a}+\dfrac{75}{10-b}=\frac{2\cdot (ma)^2}{ma\cdot ma\cdot (1-a)}+\frac{75\cdot(nb)^2}{nb\cdot nb\cdot(10-b)}.$$

If $2m=2n=1$, $ma=1-a$, and $ nb=10-b$ can all hold, we can apply **AM-GM inequality** as follows

$$\frac{2\cdot (ma)^2}{ma\cdot ma\cdot (1-a)}+\frac{75\cdot(nb)^2}{nb\cdot nb\cdot(10-b)}\geq \frac{2\cdot (ma)^2}{\left(\frac{ma
+ma+(1-a)}{3}\right)^3}+\frac{75\cdot(nb)^2}{\left(\frac{nb+nb+(10-b)}{3}\right)^3}=\cdots$$
But this is invalid, since $n=\frac{1}{2},nb=10-b$ can not satisfy $b=5$.
How to solve it?

Comment: Here is a "brute force" way with calculus (which is probably also how Wolfram Alpha obtains the result): We want to minimize $$f\left(1-\frac{b^2}{45},b\right)=\frac{2}{1-\sqrt{1-\frac{b^2}{45}}}+\frac{75}{10-b}$$ First, check the boundaries (omitted). Then notice $$f'(b)=\frac{75}{(b-10)^2}-\frac{2 b}{45 \sqrt{1-\frac{b^2}{45}} \left(1-\sqrt{1-\frac{b^2}{45}}\right)^2}$$ so $$f'(b)=0\iff -\frac{15 \left(2 \sqrt{5} b^3+25 \sqrt{45-b^2} b^2-190 \sqrt{5} b^2-2250 \sqrt{45-b^2}+200 \sqrt{5}
   b+6750 \sqrt{5}\right)}{(b-10)^2 \sqrt{45-b^2} \left(\sqrt{5} \sqrt{45-b^2}-15\right)^2}$$

Comment: which is implied by $$-15 \left(2 \sqrt{5} b^3+25 \sqrt{45-b^2} b^2-190 \sqrt{5} b^2-2250 \sqrt{45-b^2}+200 \sqrt{5} b+6750
   \sqrt{5}\right)=0.$$ This last equation is in turn equivalent to $$\sqrt{45-b^2} \left(33750-375 b^2\right)=30 \sqrt{5} b^3-2850 \sqrt{5} b^2+3000 \sqrt{5} b+101250 \sqrt{5}.$$
 Squaring both sides gives $$-140625 b^6+31640625 b^4-2278125000 b^2+51257812500=4500 b^6-855000 b^5+41512500 b^4-55125000
   b^3-2840625000 b^2+3037500000 b+51257812500$$ which can be written as $$-145125 b^6+855000 b^5-9871875 b^4+55125000 b^3+562500000 b^2-3037500000 b=0$$

Comment: which in turn can be written as $-1125 b (b-5) (129 b^4-115 b^3+8200 b^2-8000 b-540000)=0$ and thus $b=0$ or $b=5$ or $129 b^4-115 b^3+8200 b^2-8000 b-540000=0$. All the zeros of this quartic polynomial are known. Indeed, there is exactly one positive real root and it is

Comment: $$b=\frac{115}{516}+\frac{5}{516}\sqrt{-112303-\frac{53075072\ 2^{2/3}}{\sqrt[3]{84384391+24135\sqrt{24834945}}}+344 \sqrt[3]{2\left(84384391+24135 \sqrt{24834945}\right)}}+\frac12 \sqrt{-\frac{2807575}{33282}+\frac{7714400\ 2^{2/3}}{387 \sqrt[3]{84384391+24135 \sqrt{24834945}}}-\frac{50}{387} \sqrt[3]{2 \left(84384391+24135 \sqrt{24834945}\right)}+\frac{115991375}{33282 \sqrt{-112303-\frac{53075072\
   2^{2/3}}{\sqrt[3]{84384391+24135 \sqrt{24834945}}}+344\sqrt[3]{2\left(84384391+24135 \sqrt{24834945}\right)}}}}$$ Now one can check numerically that the inequality is satisfied at these points

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch, I think this would serve much better as an answer :)

Comment: @YuriyS Thanks, you are right. I am a bit busy right now but I'll maybe try to turn it into an answer tomorrow

Answer (score 3):

I come up with a solution which is based on the clue I posted above.

\begin{align*}
\frac{2}{1-a}+\frac{75}{10-b}&=\frac{2}{1-a}+\frac{15}{2}\cdot\frac{b}{10-b}+\frac{15}{2}\\
&=\frac{2\cdot \frac{a}{2}\cdot \frac{a}{2}}{(1-a)\cdot \frac{a}{2}\cdot\frac{a}{2}}+\frac{15}{2}\cdot\frac{b\cdot b}{(10-b)\cdot b}+\frac{15}{2}\\
&\ge\frac{\frac{a^2}{2}}{\left(\frac{(1-a)+\frac{a}{2}+\frac{a}{2}}{3}\right)^3}+\frac{15}{2}\cdot\frac{b^2}{\left(\frac{(10-b)+ b}{2}\right)^2}+\frac{15}{2}\\
&\ge \frac{27}{2}\left(a^2+\frac{b^2}{45}\right)+\frac{15}{2}\\
&=\frac{27}{2}\cdot1+\frac{15}{2}\\
&=21,
\end{align*}
which hold as equality iff $1-a=\dfrac{a}{2},10-b=b,$ namely $a=\dfrac{3}{2},b=5$.

Comment: +1 for a beautiful answer and just one more point: we can assume $a, b > 0$ when we do AM-GM, because we want to maximise the denominators to minimise the expression.

Comment: @TobyMak $a,b>0$ is just the given condition. No need to assume more.

Answer (score 2):

There is another way using parameterisation. Let $a = \cos t, b = \sqrt{45} \sin t$, then we have:

$$f(t) = \frac{2}{1-\cos t} + \frac{75}{10-\sqrt{45} \sin t}$$
$$f'(t) = -\frac{2 \sin t}{(1-\cos t)^2} + \frac{225 \sqrt5 \cos t}{(10-3 \sqrt{5} \sin t)^2}$$

The condition that $a,b > 0$ translates to $0 < t < \frac{\pi}{2}$. Setting $f'(t)$ equal to $0$, we find that only $0.841$ (actually $\tan^{-1} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt5} \right)$) is inside the range.

Therefore the minimum value is $f(0.841) = 21$.

Comment: Can you solve $f'(t)=0$ only by hand?

Comment: It is possible but it would take hours to do by hand. Rearranging you would get a cubic in terms of $\cos t$ equal to a cubic in terms of $\sin t$, and using $\sin t = \sqrt{1- \cos^2 t}$ (since $0 < t < \frac{\pi}{2}$) you can get everything in terms of $\sin t$. Solving using Cardano's formula should give one root as $\cos t = \sqrt{\frac{5}{6}}$ as a result which is equivalent to $t = \arctan \frac{1}{\sqrt5}$.

Answer (score 1):

The Tangent Line method helps.

Let $a=\frac{2}{3}x$ and $b=5y$.

Thus, $$4x^2+5y^2=9$$ and
$$\frac{2}{1-a}+\frac{75}{10-b}-21=3\left(\frac{2}{3-2x}+\frac{5}{2-y}-7\right)=$$
$$=3\left(\frac{2}{3-2x}-2-2(x^2-1)+\frac{5}{2-y}-5-\frac{5}{2}(y^2-1)\right)=$$
$$=\frac{6(x-1)^2(2x+1)}{3-2x}+\frac{15y(y-1)^2}{2(2-y)}\geq0.$$
The equality occurs for $x=y=1,$ which says that $21$ is a minimal value.

There is the following reasoning.

Let $$\frac{2}{1-a}+\frac{75}{10-b}=k.$$
Thus, $$b=10-\frac{75}{k-\frac{2}{1-a}}$$ and find all values of $k$ for which the equation
$$a^2+\frac{\left(10-\frac{75}{k-\frac{2}{1-a}}\right)^2}{45}=1$$ has solutions $0<a<1.$

Comment: If you do not know the minimum point is $(2/3,5)$, how to construct the proof?

Comment: @mengdie1982 If so we need to use the Lagrange Multipliers method and to solve the system.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Which should be equivalent to my ugly calculations in the comments

Comment: But this is an elementary problem, I think it can be solved by elementary methods such as  inequality

Comment: @Maximilian Janisch There is a much more easier way. I think there is a mistake in your computations.

Comment: It is easy to figure out a proof after you know the result. But what if you do not know that at all?

Comment: @mengdie1982 My solution is just elementary.

Comment: Can down-voter explain us, why did you do it?